# Changing processParameters in a TFS Build Definition

Tags: vb.net, build-process, build-automation

Typically its done using something similar to

```
    Dim dicParamValues As IDictionary(Of String, Object) = WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(pStrProcParam)
    'dicParamValues(<ProcessID>) = <Value>
    '...
    WorkflowHelpers.SerializeProcessParameters(dicParamValues)
```

But the normal processParameters in BuildDefinition did not have the parameters I needed to change.  I found them in BuildDefinition.Process.Parameters, but its not a file that can be parsed into a dictionary using WorkFlowHelpers, it is instead deserialized into an Activity.

Since there is a way to turn Activities into a dictionary list of parameters, I tried this code

```
    Dim actParamValues As Activity = WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeWorkflow(pStrProcParam)
    Dim dicParamValues As IDictionary(Of String, Object) = WorkflowHelpers.GetProcessParameters(actParamValues)
```

which I would think would work, but it returns processParameters instead of objects and I am not sure how to get them changed over or work around the problem.

I've already asked on the msdn TFS forums, but haven't received a response there yet.  Any help or hints would be appreciated.

EDIT:
It appears as if I'm an idiot.  The problem started when I couldn't set values that weren't there... well it turns out I can ADD them to the dictionary list, then set the new list without any problem (so far).

The correct code is

```
        Dim dicParamValues As IDictionary(Of String, Object) = WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(pStrProcParamShort)
    dicParamValues.Add("PublishToDevelopment", pBolDev)
    dicParamValues.Add("PublishToMainOrDemo", pBolDemo)
    dicParamValues.Add("PublishToLiveOrReleaseLocation", pBolRelease)
    Return WorkflowHelpers.SerializeProcessParameters(dicParamValues)
```

I'll try to keep an eye on this in case anyone else has a similar problem.

Comment: LOL you should have added an answer to your own question then marked your question answered. That way you'll get a self-learner badge and others from looking at the list of questions will know your question has an answer.

Comment: There was a notice that I needed to wait another 4 hours or something?  I was leaving work so I went ahead and just edited it in case someone else had a similar problem (unlikely but possible).  Next time I'll wait, didn't know there was an achievement for solving your own problem :P.